# MySql Stored Procedure out id return null

Tags: mysql, sql

I hava stored procedure, that insert into adress table, it has 3 in parametrs and 1 out parametr. If I call this procedure out parametr is null

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `insert_adress`(
                        in d varchar(50),
                        in r varchar(50),
                        in c varchar(50),
                        in adress_text varchar(255),
                        out id int)
BEGIN
    declare disc_id int;
    declare reg_id int;
    declare coun_id int;


if ((select count(*) from district where district.dist like d) <> 0)
    then set disc_id := (select id from district where district.dist like d);
    else
        insert into district(dist) values(d);
        set disc_id := (select max(id) from district);
end if;

if ((select count(*) from region where region.reg like r) <> 0)
    then set reg_id := (select id from region where region.reg like r);
    else
        insert into region(reg) values(r);
        set reg_id := (select max(id) from region);
end if;

if ((select count(*) from country where country.coun like c) <> 0)
    then set coun_id := (select id from country where country.coun like c);
    else
        insert into country(coun) values(c);
        set coun_id := (select max(id) from country);
end if;

insert into adress(district,region,country,adress_text) values(disc_id,reg_id,coun_id,adress_text);
set id := (select max(id) from adress);   
END
```

I call it:

```
set @id = 0;
call mustaqil.insert_adress('test1', 'test1', 'test1', 'test1', @id);
select @id;
```

District,Region,Country tables have 'test1' row
I except that, out id, disc_id, reg_id, coun_id should be number, but it is null
P.S : stored procedure inserts row

Comment: Change `out id int` by `out _id int` and `set id := (select max(id) from adress);` by `set _id := (select max(id) from adress);`.

Answer (score 0):

just change set id := (select max(id) from adress);
to 
select max(id) into id from adress;
it should work

Comment: what is structure of your "adress" table, is it contain id field. 
you can also use select last_insert_id() into id;  after insert statement and remove set id := (select max(id) from adress);